LWC duplicates instance when switching back lightning record tab
Im using a LWC in case record page, however when I switch the tab from the case record page to any other such as the "Welcome" or "Install a Package" the LWC is still alive. But when I go back to the case record page, a new instance of the lwc is being created and both of the instances are active. Why is this behavior?

